# How to find sweet spot for a regression model

Tags: regression

In R I have `data`

```
promotion   new_users
20          48
18          60
61          86
```

where `dim(data)=800 2`. First of all I made a correlation test and we see that there is a positive correlation between number of promotions and new users. In R I did `cor.test(data$new_users, data$promotion, method="kendall", alternative="greater")` with tau about 0.28 and a very low p-value meaning we have positive correlation.

My next goal is to find a sweet spot, ie a point very the increase of `promotion` don't affect `new_user` so much. 
In other words we want to make a function taking `promotion` as input and give `new_users` as output based on the `data` we have. And we want to see if we can find a point (sweet spot) where the increase of `promotion` don't increase the function of `promotion` so much (like a turning point of increase). 
How should this be done?

First I made a linear regression model:

```
lm.r=lm(data$new_users ~ data$promotion)
```

where `summary(lm.r)` gives me

```
Residuals:
Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-86.662 -14.657  -2.837  13.721 103.199 
Coefficients:
               Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)    36.58664    1.28070   28.57   <2e-16 ***
data$TRP.Total  1.20954    0.05506   21.97   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 24.13 on 838 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.3654,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.3646 
F-statistic: 482.5 on 1 and 838 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

How can I use my regression model to find the sweet spot ?

Or would it give even more sense to consider the rate=new_users/promotion  since we want to see how the rate changes (money spent on getting a new user).

I added a scatterplot as well. [image]

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is unclear but it seems as if you're asking about a change in the rate of new users per amount of money spent, which would seem to suggest that a linear model (which doesn't allow the slope to change) would not be much use in picking up a change. Please clarify.

Comment: Specifically, the sentence "My next goal is to find a sweet spot, ie a point very [where?] the increase of promotion don't affect new_user so much" is unclear.

Comment: Have you plotted the data? And if yes, could you post the scatterplot? It sounds like you expect `new_users` to level out (or even decrease) at some point as `promotion` increases, so let's see if this even makes any sense with these data.

Comment: I have edit my post. Could it be that it follow a logarithmic regression model where it's possible to find the sweet spot?